# Slack Bot OpenModal Error: missing_post_type

Tags: slack, slack-api, slack-dialog

I newly started with Slack Bot programming and I got an issue.

I am using Zapier as a webhook, and I created a new message with a button.

Now I want to open a modal like documented here: https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open#arg_token

For that, I make a POST Request via Zapier Webhooks like this:
[image]

Instead of that the modal opens, I get a response with an error message "error
missing_post_type"

[image]

I hope some expert can help me with this issue.

Thank you for the support!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can be found in the [linked documentation](https://api.slack.com/methods/dialog.open#errors).

> The method was called via a POST request and included a data payload, but the request did not include a Content-Type header.

You only need to add the content-type header. Then the post request should work.

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I get the error "not_authed". But I provided my token in the body. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You get this error because there is no authentication token provided. You must add your token in your request's Authorization header.

Comment: Hey Flaxel. Thank you very much. This solved my Problem. But now I got a new error. Can you help me with that?

Comment: here the link to the new issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63550032/slackbot-openmodal-error-missing-charset